# IF function returning FALSE despite data being present

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`=IF(COUNT(O:O)=1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",O2)),"L","W"))`

Is returning false, any ideas why?

I would like column P to return either 'W' or 'L' depending on if there is a '-' present in column O.

See attached images below:

[image]

Comment: You have it `=1` and there are `10` numbers and as such it returns false.  Maybe you want `>1`?

Comment: I think you want: `=(IF(O2="","",IF(--O2<0,"L","W"))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Great, thanks for your help, again!